# React Native android app crashes on npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

React Native application crashes on running `npx react-native run-android` with following logs:

```
2022-06-04 11:10:13.564 29383-29383/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com2.package_name
2022-06-04 11:10:13.592 29383-29383/? E/studio.deploy: Could not find apks for this package: com2.package_name
2022-06-04 11:10:13.610 29383-29383/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com2.package_name
2022-06-04 11:10:13.636 29383-29383/? E/studio.deploy: Could not find apks for this package: com2.package_name
2022-06-04 11:10:29.739 31814-31814/com2.package_name E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~jTL2Y76i75l5A4LneQzkXw==/com2.package_name-WYiDcTmrQmKAeGL4vS15qQ==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so in namespace classloader-namespace result: 0
2022-06-04 11:10:30.514 31814-31989/com2.package_name E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2022-06-04 11:10:32.532 31814-31993/com2.package_name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: com2.package_name, PID: 31814
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:239)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:268)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1371)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1065)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

If I use:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

and then run `npx react-native run-android` then it runs but then its not in debug mood, so if I make changes to code and to see them I have to again run both commands.